# how to count multiple row (separately)

Tags: mysql, sql

i've been learning mysql since 2 weeks ago and then i have a problem how to count values in multiple rows. in other words , i want to make a new table look like this

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/J12ve.jpg

from data like this

! https://imgur.com/undefined

currently i'm using this method

```
SELECT COUNT(id_rt)
FROM krt
WHERE id_rt = 87900;
```

and change the values (87900) manually until 100+ data

is there any option how to automatically show id_rt with count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id_rt, COUNT(*)
FROM krt
GROUP BY id_rt;
```